# Override translation path of module on yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Suppose I installed module `Foo` form a repository with composer. The module structure is like this:

```
- Foo
 |- models
 |- controllers
 |- views
 |- messages
 |- config
```

`Messages` folder of `Foo` contains translation files of module. Now I want override some translation strings of `Foo`. From [Yii2 i18n Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html) I tried to use fileMap property on configuration of translation component to map `bar` category to `bar.php` (instead of reading from `app\modules\Foo\messages`), but it does not have any effect on translations. My i18n component configuration is:

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'fileMap' => [
                'bar' => 'bar.php'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

How do i achieve my goal?

Comment: Please show us how this module register its translations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to have translations for each module contained within the module, then you need to register the translations for that module. It can't be done simply from the config file. You probably already have this in your module file,, I just include for completeness. The code is copied from the documentation, and needs to be in your module file, so in `app/modules/Foo.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\foo;

use Yii;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'app\modules\foo\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    /** Register custom translations for this module **/
        $this->registerTranslations();
    }

    public function registerTranslations()
    {

    /**This registers translations for the Foo module **/
        Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/foo/*'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/foo/messages',

    /**Tells yii where to find the translations for validation and form categories **/
            'fileMap' => [
                'modules/foo/validation' => 'validation.php',
                'modules/foo/form' => 'form.php',
                ...
            ],
        ];
    }

    public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null)
    {
        return Yii::t('modules/users/' . $category, $message, $params, $language);
    }

}
```

In your case it doesn't look like you need to provide file mapping.You could simply use this format for your files

```
[[basePath]]/LanguageID/CategoryName.php
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a list of the available categories.

If you then want to override some of the module translations you will need to specify the category to be used, like this in your config file. It specifically overrides the modules/foo/bar category.

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'modules/foo*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@app/messages',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Your translation file needs to follow a folder structure like that in the translation description, so in the above example it would be

```
app/messages/ [language code] /modules/foo/bar.php
```

Otherise, you can use `fileMap` to map to different locations, like if your bar.php file is in app/messages/[language code]

```
'fileMap' => [
'modules/foo/bar' => 'bar.php'
]
```

Comment: Joe, thanks for your comprehensive answer!. Just the note that i used module id as key on configuration. I will suggest some edit on your answer, if you see that the edit is correct, it's pleasure that apply it ;).

Comment: Sorry, but the edit you suggested won't work for the example I suggested. Your own use case may have been different, but for the answer to make sense it needs to stay as is! Thanks for the suggestion though @meysam